# Sulu CMF - Sort order in flat navigation

Tags: twig, sulu

Beside the main navigation, I want to use a second navigation context to display links in the footer of the homepage.

```
{% for item in sulu_navigation_root_flat('footer_support', 4) %}
    <li><a href="{{ sulu_content_path(item.url) }}" title="{{ item.title }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

This is working so far. The problem is that the sort order of the footer links. The order neither matches the order of the items in the backend, nor can I find a way to change that order. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Didnt you miss `data-order="{{ item.order }}"` attribute?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub sulu_navigation_root_flat already returns the items ordered by item.order. But the very order is neither the one from the backend, nor do I know how to change it.

Comment: Well, you are trying to render a tree-like structure in a flat list - This is based on the fact that you are passing `4` as the depth (and you are using `sulu_navigation_root_flat` and not `sulu_navigation_root_tree`). Please have a look at the following [article](https://sulu.io/blog/how-to-use-sulu-s-navigation-contexts), they have an example on there on how to render it like a tree and not like a flat list

Comment: @DarkBee correct, there are items from the tree structure in a flat representation. As a tree structure also has an order, one should expect to have the order applied to the flat structure, which is not the case. Again there are order numbers in item.order, but these appear to follow no logic, and I do not know how to change them.
Thanks for the article, I already studied it, no info regarding the sort order in there.

Comment: That all depends on how Sulu is storing the tree in the database of course... The real question here is how you expect the output to be like. Do you first want to read out all level 1 elements, then level 2 etc or do you want to read out the first element of level 1 and then it's children ( and it's children) etc. If it's the latter then I would start using the last snippet posted on the article I've linked

Comment: You always can have a look in the source code where `sulu_navigation_root_flat` is defined to figure out more details of course

Comment: @DarkBee good idea! I could use sulu_navigation_root_tree and then flatten it in twig At least then it should have the order of the backend. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering is matching the ordering in the Admin.

If you want to have different ordering of a Item in the Footer then in the Main Navigation you create a new Node/Page using the "Internal Link" feature of Sulu.

- Create a new page
- Save that one put it in the position where you require it for the footer navigation
- Go to the Pages "Settings" Tab of that Page/Node and Add it to the "Footer Navigation"
- Change the "Type" to "Internal Link".

This way you can add a Link at any position of your Footer or other Navigations.

Comment: Cannot confirm that the ordering is matching the one of the Admin, at least not in my understanding.
Thanks for your solution!, as I am new to Sulu I need to digest that first and try it out. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, this works. It's so simple, I should have come up with that idea myself. The concept of navigaiton contexts misleaded me a bit.

Comment: Only Sulu Controllers (DefaultController, WebsiteController) or all using there renderStructure method are cached by default. If you create a normal Symfony controller it is not cached, if you want to cache it you need to set the response to public and define the "X-Reverse-Proxy-TTL" header. https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/347f0957917f9ac5e91b96fa4d668abe1e12fb6d/src/Sulu/Bundle/HttpCacheBundle/CacheLifetime/CacheLifetimeEnhancer.php#L75-L80

Comment: Hi Alexander. I suppose your last comment was directed to another question I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806585/when-multiple-users-access-the-sulu-cmf-site-the-user-context-suddenly-changes
But, thanks, now I got it. Appreciate your work!